# Android - Sending SMS to a phone using the IMEI number of the recepient?

Tags: android, sms, google-cloud-messaging, imei

I am developing an android app, through which the user can lock the phone, or factory reset the phone using SMS from another phone(accompanied by a password ofcourse) incase the phone gets stolen. I was wondering whether it is possible to send SMS to the stolen phone using its IMEI number(Incase the theif replaced the SIM card)? I want to include this facility in my app. Is there anyway Google Cloud messaging could be used for this purpose, to send a message to my application on a particular android phone.....? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use GCM for this purpose.

If you setup your app to use push notifications, while it is installed on the phone, you may contact it by push notifications (e.g. GCM), if there is an internet connection available. There is no need to know IMEI of the device, till GCM will use a registration token which will be your target, to send push notifications to.